# Spark job gets stuck indefinitely while trying to fetch data from ignite cluster

Tags: ignite, apache-spark-2.0

```
private static final ThreadLocal<IgniteClient> igniteClientContext = new ThreadLocal<>();


public static IgniteClient getIgniteClient(String[] address) {
    if(igniteClientContext.get() == null) {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = null;
        if(cfg == null) {
            clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses(address);
        } else {
            clientConfig = cfg;
        }
        IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(clientConfig);
        logger.info("igniteClient initialized ");
        igniteClientContext.set(igniteClient);
    }
    return igniteClientContext.get();
}
```

From spark code, I'm trying to create instance of ignite thin client and create cache object.

```
val address = config.igniteServers.split(",") // config.igniteServers ="10.xx.xxx.xxx:10800,10.xx.xx.xxx:10800"
```

Below code will be called from spark executor. We will be processing set or records in each executor and we are only reading data from cache and comparing with currently processing record. If it is already present in cache, we will ignore otherwise we will consume it.

```
val cacheCfg = new ClientCacheConfiguration()
      .setName(PNR_CACHE)
      .setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED)
      .setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC)
      .setDefaultLockTimeout(30000)
val igniteClient = IgniteHelper.getIgniteClient(address)
val cache : ClientCache[Long, Boolean] = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);
```

At the end of the job, we will be updating cache with all valid records.
This has been running fine for couple of runs and at some point, it gets stuck indefinitely while trying to read data from cache.

In Executor logs, I can see IgniteClusterUnavailable exception.

```
org.apache.ignite.client.ClientConnectionException: Ignite cluster is unavailable [sock=Socket[addr=hdpct2ldap01g02.hadoop.sgdcprod.XXXX.com/10.xx.xx.xx,port=10800,localport=20214]]
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.handleIOError(TcpClientChannel.java:499)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.handleIOError(TcpClientChannel.java:491)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.access$100(TcpClientChannel.java:92)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel$ByteCountingDataInput.read(TcpClientChannel.java:538)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel$ByteCountingDataInput.readInt(TcpClientChannel.java:572)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.processNextResponse(TcpClientChannel.java:272)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.receive(TcpClientChannel.java:234)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.service(TcpClientChannel.java:171)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.service(ReliableChannel.java:160)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.request(ReliableChannel.java:187)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpIgniteClient.getOrCreateCache(TcpIgniteClient.java:124)
at com.XXXX.eda.pnr.PnrApplication$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PnrApplication.scala:305)
at com.XXXX.eda.pnr.PnrApplication$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PnrApplication.scala:297)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:217)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1094)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1085)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1020)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1085)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:811)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:381)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel$ByteCountingDataInput.read(TcpClientChannel.java:535)
    ... 24 more
20/06/21 05:49:42 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 1949
20/06/21 05:49:42 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 103.1 in stage 25.0 (TID 1949)
```

Threaddump contains below exception as well.

```
20/06/21 05:51:57 WARN hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.93.133.157:20952 remote=host.hadoop.sgdcprod.XXXX.com/10.93.133.136:1004]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.vintPrefixed(PBHelper.java:2354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil.readSaslMessage(DataTransferSaslUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.doSaslHandshake(SaslDataTransferClient.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.getEncryptedStreams(SaslDataTransferClient.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.send(SaslDataTransferClient.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.checkTrustAndSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.peerSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.net.TcpPeerServer.peerFromSocketAndKey(TcpPeerServer.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:666)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.seekToBlockSource(DFSInputStream.java:1663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readBuffer(DFSInputStream.java:877)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:913)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:981)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.avro.mapred.FsInput.read(FsInput.java:54)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader$SeekableInputStream.read(DataFileReader.java:210)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder$InputStreamByteSource.readRaw(BinaryDecoder.java:824)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.doReadBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:349)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readFixed(BinaryDecoder.java:302)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.nextRawBlock(DataFileStream.java:293)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNext(DataFileStream.java:198)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anon$1.hasNext(DefaultSource.scala:215)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1094)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1085)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1085)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:381)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20/06/21 05:51:57 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to host.hadoop.sgdcprod.XXXX.com/10.93.133.136:1004 for block BP-1009813635-10.93.133.107-1555169940973:blk_1182405155_108738113, add to deadNodes and continue. 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/10.93.133.157:20952 remote=host.hadoop.sgdcprod.XXXX.com/10.93.133.136:1004]
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.vintPrefixed(PBHelper.java:2354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.DataTransferSaslUtil.readSaslMessage(DataTransferSaslUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.doSaslHandshake(SaslDataTransferClient.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.getEncryptedStreams(SaslDataTransferClient.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.send(SaslDataTransferClient.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.checkTrustAndSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.sasl.SaslDataTransferClient.peerSend(SaslDataTransferClient.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.net.TcpPeerServer.peerFromSocketAndKey(TcpPeerServer.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:666)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.seekToBlockSource(DFSInputStream.java:1663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readBuffer(DFSInputStream.java:877)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:913)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:981)
    at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream.read(CryptoInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
    at org.apache.avro.mapred.FsInput.read(FsInput.java:54)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader$SeekableInputStream.read(DataFileReader.java:210)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder$InputStreamByteSource.readRaw(BinaryDecoder.java:824)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.doReadBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:349)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readFixed(BinaryDecoder.java:302)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.nextRawBlock(DataFileStream.java:293)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.hasNext(DataFileStream.java:198)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1$$anon$1.hasNext(DefaultSource.scala:215)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1094)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1085)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1020)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1085)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:381)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**We are setting defaultReadTimeout in spark.properties file. But it is not getting timedout correctly.
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseG1GC -Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout:300000 -Dsun   .net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=300000 -DIGNITE_REST_START_ON_CLIENT=true
spark.driver.exetraJavaOptions=-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout:300000 -Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=300000 -DIGNITE_REST_START_ON_CLIENT=true**

Please help in resolving the issue.

Ignite version using : 2.8.0 & 2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

There is some connectivity problem with HDFS and Ignite cluster from your Spark cluster:

HDFS:

```
WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to host.hadoop.sgdcprod.XXXX.com/10.93.133.136:1004 for block BP-1009813635-10.93.133.107-1555169940973:blk_1182405155_108738113, add to deadNodes and continue.
```

And for Ignite:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out (Read failed)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
```

Taking into account that your spark job wasn't able to connect both of them then I guess that you have the problem with connectivity there.

However please check the following for HDFS:

1)Some of your Spark workers can't connect host.hadoop.sgdcprod.XXXX.com/10.93.133.136:1004 address because of closed ports or some connectivity issues. You can try to check this address via some tool like netstat.

2)You are going to use an incorrect HDFS port. Please check that the HDFS URL of namenode used in your Spark job code is correct.

3)Something wrong with your configuration of HDFS workers. Probably some of them can't connect to name node.

And for IGNITE:

1)Check that your cluster is alive and doesn't hang. I hope that your cluster was started somewhere outside and can be available via some monitoring tool.

2)Check that server addresses from IP finder can be resolved from every Spark worker.